# mySQL, multiple foreign keys pointing to same PK

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have a table with timestamps (Points) and a table with timestamp **pairs ** (Linked) and i am lookin for a smart way to get the time difference between the pairs of the Linked table. i am a bit lost with the 2 foreign keys referring to the same PK :(

```
CREATE TABLE `Points` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TStamp` datetime ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ;
CREATE TABLE `Linked` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prevID` int,
  `nextID` int ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `prevID_idx` (`prevID`),
  KEY `nxtID_idx` (`nextID`),
  CONSTRAINT `nxtID` FOREIGN KEY (`nextID`) REFERENCES `Points` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `prevID` FOREIGN KEY (`prevID`) REFERENCES `Points` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;
```

expecting to get the time difference between the timestamps of each pair in Linked table

Comment: FK is a a distraction..

Answer (score 0):

> i am a bit lost with the 2 foreign keys referring to the same PK

To solve this, you give the table **aliases** in your query so you can treat it as if it was 2 separate tables:

```
SELECT pointsPREV.Tstamp, pointsNEXT.Tstamp
FROM linked
JOIN points pointsPREV
ON linked.prevID=pointsPREV.ID
JOIN points pointsNEXT
ON linked.nextID=pointsNEXT.ID
```